# Do an action with a mail selected, that moves that mail into a folder in the corresponding bank/account/mailbox

Tags: vba, email, outlook, directory, default

I have a code to move a mail into a folder created with the name of the expeditor.
But I have 4 different mails bank/account (one with ".fr",the second with ".com"..), and by default, the folders are all created (and the mails are moved) in the first and main account, so my mails are mixed.

The bit of code actually used is :

---

### Set myRoot = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

I tried to look at the object explorer in the VBA outlook macro interface, but I just found Getdefaultfolder (in namespace or store class), that I don't really understand. I didn't found the "session" thing, and nothing seems to compile effectively aside for the actual bit of code..

Do you have any idea for my code to work in the same "mail bank" than the selected mail ?
Thanks you so much !

Overflowly,
Keyo

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to move an Outlook item to the folder in the same store. The [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

```
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores 
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
 Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
 Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
 EnumerateFolders oRoot 
 Next 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub EnumerateFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder) 
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders 
 Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim foldercount As Integer 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set folders = oFolder.folders 
 foldercount = folders.Count 
 'Check if there are any folders below oFolder 
 If foldercount Then 
 For Each Folder In folders 
 Debug.Print (Folder.FolderPath) 
 EnumerateFolders Folder 
 Next 
 End If 
End Sub
```

So, you need to find the store instance which corresponds to the expeditor (email) and move the item there.

Comment: Okay, I tried to replace Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
by Session.Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
and Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
but I get "error 438=method/propriety isn't managed by this object."...
(what is session?)

Comment: The `Namespace` class provides the `Stores` property, not `Store.`

Comment: I've pasted some code which shows how to deal with Stores.

Answer (score 0):

With `.Parent` work upwards from the known item to the folder it is in, to the folder above that until the inbox.

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
'
' If desperate declare as variant

Sub selectionParent()

Dim currItem As Object  ' not mailitem

Dim curFolder As Folder
Dim myRoot As Folder

' select a mailitem in an inbox or subfolder of an inbox
Set currItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

If currItem.Class = olMail Then

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print currItem.Subject
    
    Set curFolder = currItem.Parent
    
    ' safest to compare text after LCase or UCase
    Do Until LCase(curFolder.name) = LCase("inbox")
        Debug.Print " curFolder.name: " & curFolder.name
        Set curFolder = curFolder.Parent
    Loop
    
    ' This is the inbox folder associated with the selected item
    Set myRoot = curFolder
    Debug.Print " myRoot: " & myRoot
    Debug.Print " The mailbox is myRoot.Parent: " & myRoot.Parent

Else

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "** not a mailtem **"
    
End If

End Sub
```

In practical terms `Session` is equivalent to `GetNamespace("MAPI")`. Saves some lines of code.

Any of these three versions gives the same result.

```
Private Sub session_LineSaver_NamespaceMapi()

    Dim inboxFldr As Folder
    
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Session"
    Set inboxFldr = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Debug.Print " inboxFldr: " & inboxFldr
    Debug.Print " inboxFldr.Parent: " & inboxFldr.Parent
    
    
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "GetNamespace - not best practice, harder to see errors"
    Set inboxFldr = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Debug.Print " inboxFldr: " & inboxFldr
    Debug.Print " inboxFldr.Parent: " & inboxFldr.Parent
    
    
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "GetNamespace - create a separate object for the namespace"
    Dim nS As Namespace             ' extra line
    Set nS = GetNamespace("MAPI")   ' extra line
    
    Set inboxFldr = nS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Debug.Print " inboxFldr: " & inboxFldr
    Debug.Print " inboxFldr.Parent: " & inboxFldr.Parent

End Sub
```